# Customize add unimplemented method in eclipse based on condition

Tags: eclipse

i want to customize the add unimplemented method functionality of the eclipse. means instead of generated one single code i wants that it will generate the code based on some condition.

For example : I have some methods in interface and a class implement that interface. On the top eclipse show the warning that "Add unimplmented methods". When i click on it, it will add blank implementation of that methods.

I want that when i click on "Add unimplmented methods" then it will add some code based on the file name.

If i have method

```
public int addTwoIntegers(int one, int two);
```

in my interface then

when i click on "Add unimplemented methods" then it will add following:

```
public int addTwoIntegers(int one, int two){    
System.out.println(one);
return null;
}
```

The code that is added is vary based on the file name.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the method body template at 'Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates'.

Looking at the available template variables might also help - http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm